# What should i send GET or POST if field calculating based on query params?

Tags: rest, post, get, query-string

I have resource `/api/v1/serviced-objects/` and when i send regular `GET` request, i get server response and each element in it contains `distance` field which has `null` value.

```json
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "point": "0,30",
      "distance": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "point": "30,0",
      "distance": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Also i have query param `user_point`. If i send `GET` request like `/api/v1/serviced-objects/?user_point=0,0`, i'll get calculated value for `distance` field between given `user_point` and serviced object point in meters.

```json
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "point": "0,30",
      "distance": 2000
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "point": "30,0",
      "distance": 1000
    }
  ]
}
```

So general question is - Is it still idempotent or it's better to use `POST` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

How you choose between using a `GET` request with query parameters or a `POST` request relies on how you think about the process of calculating and updating the `distance` field in your application's context. Using the `GET` request is acceptable if the action primarily involves *retrieving resources*. A `POST` request on the other hand, would be more appropriate if it's about *creating or modifying a resource*.

In the given example, the inclusion of the `user_point` parameter and `distance` field calculation does not affect the idempotency of the `GET` request because *more probably* no data is being modified on the server and it is simply retrieving information based on the provided parameter. While the response may differ based on the `user_point` parameter, requests with the same `user_point` value should always produce the same response.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is till the time you are not modifying any resource value in your system you should go for the `GET` request, otherwise `POST`